# What happen to async member function after local object out of scope?

Tags: c++

For example, if I can call an async function like this:

```
{
    Example example;
    example.asyncFuncInside();
}
```

Since the object is freed after the scope, will it have any risks on the ongoing task running inside the async function?

Comment: depends on what `asyncFuncInside();` is and whether the asynchronous part of it needs `example` to be alive

Comment: Yeah. Definitely bad. It still call it. Undefined behavior, because you don't know what will be at that location anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be answered in the current form. If the "async" is a detached `std::thread`, nothing bad happens. If the async function was implemented using `std::async`, on the other hand, then `asyncFuncInside` would return its `std::future`, and since that's ignored the dtor of `std::future` would block.

Comment: Sorry, but why for a detached std::thread nothing bad happens? I imagine accessing all the member variables will be risky after the local object is destroyed?

Comment: @Michael: Accessing members of a destroyed object is indeed bad, but that is a bad idea regardless of how it happens. So we first assume that the non-thread code is correct, and then we consider if `std::thread::detach` breaks anything.